# Flutter - how to populate GridView items in columns, not in rows

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Currently this is order in which items are added to the `GridView.builder`:

[image: current behaviour]

My question is -- how to make them added in **this** order?

[image: desired behaviour]

GridView's scroll direction must remain vertical.

Here's example of `GridView` I'm using:

```
Widget gridViewBuilder () {
  return GridView.builder(
     gridDelegate: 
        new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          mainAxisSpacing: 1,
        ),
       itemCount: 3,
       itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
          itemForGridview(i, context);
  );
}
```

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Added in the description

Comment: It's kinda against to logic of gridview, if you check it's document it says "The main axis direction of a grid is the direction in which it scrolls (the scrollDirection)."

Comment: @Lunedor I understand. What I want is to populate gridview items by mainAxis, not by crossaxis (standard behavior). Maybe some tricks in sorting items, if it's not possible in any way?

Comment: Sorry I tried a few tricks which comes in my mind but couldn't figure out yet. But I believe anything is possible in flutter but I prefer clean ones so I will research a bit more.

Comment: @Lunedor Sure, thanks. I've tried a few tricks as well, but this task turned out to be more tricky than I expected

Comment: If you find a trick also, how would you know when to stop populating vertically and switch to another column?

Comment: @ShubhamGupta That's the point. I tried to divide items count on the desired amount of columns to get size of each

Comment: I tried using columns and seems to work. Check it out and let me know if that's what you need. You can find the code here [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/a3d917d87e07aae8fbb5f1213866f313)

Comment: @ShubhamGupta Yeah, that's it. But it's a little bit of hack here, since you omitted using `GridView.builder`, and just manually placed items in row of columns

Comment: I don't think Using `Gridview.builder` it's possible. You can wrap it with SingleChildScrollView to achieve the scrolling.I'll post it as an answer, I hope it helps others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think with `GridView.builder` that behavior is possible. Here is a simple workaround for the same.

You can use `Row` with n `Column` where n is the CrossAxisCount as in `GridView`.
Then we simply divide the data and assign 1st half to first `Column` and the remaining to the 2nd `Column`.

```
final List<int> numbers = List.generate(10, (index) => index);

Row(
  children: [
    Column(
      children: List.generate(numbers.length ~/ 2,
          (index) => getContainer(numbers[index].toString())).toList(),
    ),
    Column(
      children: List.generate(
          numbers.length ~/ 2,
          (index) => getContainer(
              numbers[numbers.length ~/ 2 + index].toString())).toList(),
    ),
  ],
);
```

And the getContainer can be any desired widget.For simplicity, we take a Container.

```
Widget getContainer(String number) {
  return Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text(
        number,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: The flaw of this decision is that row of columns can't be filled with data dynamically - for example, you can't change the amount of columns on the fly, as you can with `GridView`. Also, layout should be hardcoded, instead of automatic layouting of `GridView`

Comment: You can change the Columns on the fly , there is no need for hardcoding the Layout. As we are generating the column data the same way we can generate the Row data. I made a simple prototype for the same it works fine till `column-count` of `5`.You can try out the same [here](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/755048d9062f83c735ead06fdbc7e563). As you can see the layout is not hardcoded and it works as intended. Working on improving the current algorithm to generate the columns as I get the wrong layout if I go above 5 columns.

Comment: I just tried your solution, and actually it works in my case, by wrapping rows and columns in `ListView.builder`. However, it's not perfect solution, so I gave you + but won't accept yet